# Почему символы валют в html не отображаются в некоторых браузерах?

Tags: html

В своём проекте я использую символ российского рубля, вводя в html-разметку код 
`&#8381;`. Это работает на моём домашнем компьютере(Windows 10, Chrome), на моём Android-устройстве(Android 6.0, Chrome), на iPhone 7 в Safari тоже. Но вчера я протестировал свой сайт на компьютере с Windows 7 и там вместо иконки рубля был просто квадрат. То же касается символа гривны. Что есть причиной этому и есть ли какое-то решение для этого случая? Font Awesome не подходит, поскольку в нём нет иконки украинской гривны и ещё нескольких важных валютных иконок.

Comment: Возьмите шрифт с системы в которой всё работает(*проверьте лицензии*) и экспортируйте его в css.

Answer (score 1):

В шрифте его нет, подгружайте шрифт через `@font-face`.
Я имею в виду веб-шрифты `web-fonts`.

Answer (score 0):

Вам подойдет [сервис генерации иконочных шрифтов](http://fontello.com/). Там нет ни символа рубля, ни тем более гривны, но вы можете нарисововать их (или взять откуда-то) и загрузить на сайт в формате SVG-шрифта. Сервис сгененрирует шрифты и необходимые файлы для встраивания иконок на сайт.